# filtering data from firebase-realtime-database

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to get data from firebase with value of user's username. I've tried 2 different method a week ago, but now I'm back at it, I noticed I've deleted it.

Here inside home.ts where I subscribe the data

```
this.database.list<EventModels>('event-list').valueChanges().subscribe((eventData) => { 

}, (err)=>{
 console.log("Error while retrieving event details : ", err);
}); 

this.eventListRef$ = this.database.list<EventModels>('event-list');
this.eventList$ = this.eventListRef$.snapshotChanges()
.pipe(
  map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({ id: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
  )
);
```

The data I want to filter is equal to creator

[image]

Since I set creator to user's email, I want to list all event that was created by the user only, by using `== firebase.auth().currentUser.email` and all the one that I've tried failed.

Answer (score 2):

From the [AngularFire documentation on querying lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md):

> ```
> db.list('/items', ref => ref.orderByChild('size').equalTo('large'))
> ```

So it looks like yours should be something like:

```
this.eventListRef$ = this.database.list<EventModels>('event-list', 
  ref => firebase.database().ref("event-list").orderByChild("email").equalTo(firebase.auth().currentUser.email));
```